# How do I plot a collected data set (x1, t1) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, machine-learning

I need to import data from two txt files and plot it out. t1: target variable, x1: input variable, t1 has to be plotted as a function of x1.

Comment: Can you provide a pseudo-code example or present what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your files are just a row (or column) of numbers, you can easily do so with

```
x1=load('textfile1.txt')
t1=load('textfile2.txt')
plot(x1,t1)
```

You should also make sure your current directory on matlab is the one containing the text files. Alternatively use cd(PATH) with PATH being the directory, or supply the load function filenames that include their path.